# accessing two websites (built using mvc) simultaneously giving error message

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am  trying to access to two websites simultaneously, both built using MVC.  If I`m logged In in one, I can`t access the other.   How can I correct the following?

I am having the error message:

> Unable to validate data. 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Unable to validate data.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to validate data.]
>   System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.EncryptOrDecryptData(Boolean
>   fEncrypt, Byte[] buf, Byte[] modifier, Int32 start, Int32 length,
>   Boolean useValidationSymAlgo, Boolean useLegacyMode, IVType ivType,
>   Boolean signData) +4956871
>   System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.EncryptOrDecryptData(Boolean
>   fEncrypt, Byte[] buf, Byte[] modifier, Int32 start, Int32 length,
>   Boolean useValidationSymAlgo, Boolean useLegacyMode, IVType ivType)
>   +155    System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(String encryptedTicket) +283
>   MvcUI.MvcApplication.FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(Object sender,
>   FormsAuthenticationEventArgs args) in
>   C:\Hg\MyProject\Code\MvcUI\Global.asax.cs:40
>   System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticate(FormsAuthenticationEventArgs
>   e) +11497690
>   System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule.OnEnter(Object source,
>   EventArgs eventArgs) +88
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +80    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +270

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.237

---

New error message after inserting the same machine key for both apps

> Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: value 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value

Source Error:

> Line 71:          { Line 72:              user =
>   myProject.API.User.Load(userName); Line 73:
>                 HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(key, user, null, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, Line 74:                      new
>   TimeSpan(0, 2, 0), System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Default,
>   null); Line 75:           }
>
> [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: value]
>      System.Web.Caching.CacheEntry..ctor(String key, Object value, CacheDependency dependency, CacheItemRemovedCallback onRemovedHandler, DateTime utcAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan slidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority priority, Boolean isPublic) +8942559
>      System.Web.Caching.CacheInternal.DoInsert(Boolean isPublic, String key, Object value, CacheDependency dependencies, DateTime utcAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan slidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority priority, CacheItemRemovedCallback onRemoveCallback, Boolean replace) +93
>      System.Web.Caching.Cache.Add(String key, Object value, CacheDependency dependencies, DateTime absoluteExpiration, TimeSpan slidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority priority, CacheItemRemovedCallback onRemoveCallback) +81
>      MvcUI.MvcApplication.GetUserFromCache(String userName) in C:\Dev\myProject\Code\MvcUI\Global.asax.cs:73
>      MvcUI.MvcApplication.FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(Object sender, FormsAuthenticationEventArgs args) in C:\Dev\myProject\Code\MvcUI\Global.asax.cs:40
>      System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticate(FormsAuthenticationEventArgs e) +9043237
>      System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule.OnEnter(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs) +84
>      System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +148
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75

---

Global.asax.cs

> public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
>       {
>           public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
>           {
>               filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
>           }

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("WebService/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }

    public void FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(object sender, FormsAuthenticationEventArgs args)
    {
        if (FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported)
        {
            if (null != Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName])
            {
                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value);
                args.User = new myProject.Web.UI.Classes.UserPrincipal(GetUserFromCache(ticket.Name));
            }
        }
        else
            throw new HttpException("Cookieless Forms Authentication is not supported for this application.");
    }

    public void WindowsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(object sender, WindowsAuthenticationEventArgs args)
    {
        string username = args.Identity.Name.Substring(args.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\\") + 1);
        myProject.API.User user = GetUserFromCache(username);

        if (null == user)
            throw new HttpException("User could not be found.");

        args.User = new myProject.Web.UI.Classes.UserPrincipal(user);
    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    private static myProject.API.User GetUserFromCache(string userName)
    {
        string key = "User " + userName;
        myProject.API.User user = (myProject.API.User)HttpContext.Current.Cache[key];
        if (null == user)
        {
            user = myProject.API.User.Load(userName);
            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(key, user, null, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,
                    new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0), System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Default, null);
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears the same authentication cookie is being used.

Comment: @leppie how can I correct that?

Comment: have you tried the solutions that Softion and I gave? Any feedback?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to all of you for having tried to reply to the question.  Indeed they were all helpful.  I solved the problem myself by adding a machinekey to the wenconfig, as well as a form name had to be there.  without te form name, even the machine key was not useful

Comment: I added the machineKey in my web.config but it' doen't work: `<machineKey validationKey="2D22CD7A956C67564FF77D740FF1377A71A3F5AEA01D8455CC53FA76F90DFF46D721A435FE7CCCF02FFFD7CA51816A69F1E86799E09F8AF698DCB56B387497F3" decryptionKey="9B2E487F2BA9785B0D427A2D911FC911C04F4AD48062D0AE1EC0C424E4D752DF" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />` What do you mean with the **form name**. Regards

Comment: Ok. the problem is when the client is using remote desktop. Why? Maybe some security issue update? Regards.

Comment: Can you describe what is 'form name'?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you are using Forms Authentication? Maybe both cookies are created using the same domain but different machine keys.

So when site A creates the cookie (guy logs in) and you then go to site B (not logged in), site B looks at the domain and says hey this guy is logged in lets decrypt the data, but because the cookie was encrypted using MACHINE KEY A, it fails.

My 2c :)

Comment: I have no idea what Gor Auth. is :) can you give me a link? There should be a config area where you select the domain for your cookie, make sure that both sites have different domains

Comment: I am using Forms Authetication.

Comment: ok then in the web.config under the "authentication" node you will see a "forms" node. You can just add a domain="DOMAINNAME" attribute on there. Make sure they are different for both the sites.

Comment: the problem is that both sites must have the same domain, since they will be ued by the same person.

Comment: I have followed certain instructions from Softion, and after that I am having some other errors.  Please see edited part to hae more information.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that :

1) your websites use 2 different autogenerated MachineKey. The MachineKey is the constant key used to encode/decode the content of the form authentication cookie, hash passwords, ...

2) you used the same applicationName in both apps.

3) I would also guess that you are trying to setup a beta website and a production website on the same machine.

Comment: I have generated machine key from a site online and inserted in both apps.  Now I am having another error: [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value]
   System.Web.Caching.CacheEntry..ctor(String key, Object value, CacheDependency dependency, CacheItemRemovedCallback onRemovedHandler, DateTime utcAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan slidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority priority, Boolean isPublic) +8942559
  Please see edited part to have full error message

Comment: What do you mean by application Name? Is it the assembly name or solution name?  The solution name are different but not assembly name

Comment: The beta website and production website are not on the same machine

Comment: that error message looks completely unrelated at first glance. You are trying to get/load a user from cache and it is failing. What is happening in the Global.asax? Have you got code in the Application start or in begin request in the global.asax?

Comment: The error message I have in the edited part is occuring when I inserted the same machine key for both apps.

Comment: When you change the machine key, you must reset the user database (aspnet_* tables) as crypted profiles, passwords, sessions, and other things depending on machine key will not work anymore.

Comment: The application name is set in the web.config file at several places. Search applicationName in web.config. Example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164644.aspx

Comment: One application (web site app) must have a unique application name if more than one application is using the same aspnet_* database.